# Measurement protocol not working for mobile app

Tags: google-analytics, measurement

I am trying to send data about screenview in my account Google Analytics, using measurement protocol.
But i don't see data in the Real Time reports.
string request:

```
http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-55175445-4&cid=666&t=screenview&an=HelloWorld
```

where is a problem?

Answer (score 5):

I had same problem and apparently if you're using mobile app version of analytics you have to send application name (an) and application id (aid), otherwise the hit is ignored.

Comment: Worked for me. Just for clarification: "an" is an app name, specified in GA, "aid" is an ios app bundle id.

Comment: Thanks! I only needed to set `an`. How can this not be documented?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some bullets you might want to consider.

1) Make sure that you are using google universal. ([How?](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/4457764?hl=en))

2) For new google analytics accounts it will take up to 48 hours until you can start using the measurement protocol.

3) Make sure you are setting the User-Agent with the request

4) Make sure cid is a random UUID (version 4) as described in http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt